Replacing string values with one of the sequence-functions
Given the following list of rules (which might contain duplicate
keys), I want to replace the string values with the first preceding numerical value.
list = {
   "a" -> 7, "b" -> 5, "d" -> "y", "a" -> "x", "km" -> "x", "n" -> 8,
   "v" -> 51, "w" -> 75, "ya" -> "x", "bt" -> "zz", "h" -> 21};

This gives the expected result, but needs NestWhile to apply
SequenceReplace repeatedly.
NestWhile[
 SequenceReplace[#, {(a_ -> n_?NumberQ), (b_ -> _String)} :> Sequence[a -> n, b -> n]] &,
 list,
 UnsameQ,
 2]


{"a" -> 7, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 5, "a" -> 5, "km" -> 5, "n" -> 8,
"v" -> 51, "w" -> 75, "ya" -> 75, "bt" -> 75, "h" -> 21}

Is it possible to get the above result with one of the
sequence-functions, but without the use of NestWhile,
FixedPoint or similar constructs?

You may achieve this with a simple ReplaceAll: list /. {HoldPattern[x_ -> y_] :>     If[NumericQ[y], num = y; x -> y, x -> num]}

sr = SequenceReplace[{a : (_ -> n_?NumberQ), b : (_ -> _String) ..} :>
    Sequence[a, Splice[# -> n & @@@ {b}]]]

sr @ list


{"a" -> 7, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 5, "a" -> 5, "km" -> 5, "n" -> 8,   
 "v" -> 51, "w" -> 75, "ya" -> 75, "bt" -> 75, "h" -> 21}



list //. {a___, b_ -> kb_?NumberQ, c_ -> kc_String, d___} :> {a, 
   b -> kb, c -> kb, d}
(*{"a" -> 7, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 5, "a" -> 5, "km" -> 5, "n" -> 8, 
 "v" -> 51, "w" -> 75, "ya" -> 75, "bt" -> 75, "h" -> 21}*)


Thank you, +1, but I would like to see a solution with SequenceReplace, SequenceSplit or similar functions.

I find it slightly easier to focus on just the Values since the Keys don't matter.
SubsetMap[
  SequenceReplace[
    seq : {num_?NumberQ, __String} :> Splice[ConstantArray[num, Length@seq]]], list, {All, 2}]


Thread[Keys[#] -> First@Values[#]] & /@ Split[list, Head[Last@#2] == String &] 
   // Flatten

(* {"a" -> 7, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 5, "a" -> 5, "km" -> 5, "n" -> 8, 
    "v" -> 51, "w" -> 75, "ya" -> 75, "bt" -> 75, "h" -> 21} *)

